# Split View inside of a Tab Bar in an iPad Application

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

When the iPad first came out, I recall that Apple frowned upon the use of a Split View inside of Tab Bar Item View.  Whether or not they rejected applications that used this design I don't recall or know anything of.

Is this design still frowned upon by Apple?  If you create an application that uses this design will it be rejected by Apple?  I know there are third-party API's now that help you write applications that utilize this design pattern which leads me to believe that Apple no longer cares, but I just wanted to be sure about this.

If anyone can shed some light on why Apple frowned upon this design that would be helpful because I don't understand what about this design was an issue for Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the citation at the moment, but there used to be a section in the HIG that said that you *must* not do this, and then they changed it to one saying you should *try to avoid* doing this. So I think you're clear, as long as the design makes sense. Sadly I can't find where that phrase occurred — maybe it was taken out all together.

At any rate, there's nothing in the HIG under either tab bar or split view that says you can't do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll take a look at the HIG and see if I can find anything in there as well.

Comment: Just wanted to follow-up.  I took a look at the HIG and didn't see any specific references to this issue.  Perhaps Apple did step away from trying to force this design stance upon us.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just stepped over this, too.

This also didn't work in the Interface-Builder prior to 5.1.

But i just tried today and recognized that you can simply add a relationship from a tabbar controller to a splitview inside interface builder (this did not work before).

However, only the detail view shows up when running the app and select the tab containing the splitview.

edit: This seems to work out very easy if you compile for 5.1. There seems to be a change in handling Splitviews.

Just try it out:

- In your Storyboard, create a Tabbar Controller
- add a Split View Controller
- Create a Reference from the Tabbar Controller to the Split View Controller

Now you need to create your Master and Detail Controllers

I am not finished with the implementation yet, but hope this helps.